# Should I clear up a small space with snow against a window?

Tags: windows, snow

I have about a 10cm wide gap between my Tempo and my house. And, with the winter snow, that space has filled with snow.

Now, should I go and clear that space of the snow (because it could damage the house) or is it all right and I should just let it be?

My gut is telling me its allright because the snow insulates the house just a little bit more, but I could just be wrong.

[image]

Comment: Are the outside sashes wood? Wood + Water + Time = Rot.

Comment: Those have been changed in the last few years, so I don't think its wood (I do not have to sand and retreat them). Feels like a plastic-y material from inside. I have windows on the second floor that the snow is currently almost touching, I guess those I'll have to clear up. Even if I would guess if its not ground floor any water that melted will just melt back to the ground and don't do that much damage.

Comment: What is a "Tempo"?

Comment: A car shelter. I guess in Quebec its got the 'Frigidaire' problem where we use the name of the brand instead of the name of the thing because I've always heard it referred as a tempo. https://abristempo.com/en/

Comment: #TIL. Thanks. Definitely not a term used south of the boarder.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, snow insulates if it's air tight. Seems like plenty of space between the snow and window for fierce windchill to set in.

Assuming the window is at least double-pane and doing it's job with argon gas then there is not much benefit to having the snow there.

Consider this, the snow will melt and re-freeze several times throughout the season so you're better off preventing the melt from infiltrating the window frame and re-freezing. The sash might not rot but ice doesn't care about the material; water will freeze, expand, and damage, period.

Additionally, don't forget that your window is constantly losing heat and causing this melt-freeze cycle. The weather doesn't have to be above 32F in order for that snow to melt.

Answer (score 1):

The points already made in the above answers are accurate and should be considered. However, I think it's always wise to remove sources of moisture away from the foundation of a house for the same reason it's wise to channel rain water away from the foundation. Moisture on siding of any type and around a foundation can only cause problems.

Comment: Agree here and that is why swiss chalets and most house builds in CH have overhanging roofs to reduce snow in contact with walls like the OP shows.